# redux-toolket react-redux typescript connect error

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I create my project by create-react-app test --template redux-typescript, then I rewrite /src/features/counter/Counter.tsx by connect but not hooks, then vscode give this error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { RootState, AppDispatch } from '../../app/store';
import {
  decrement,
  increment,
  incrementByAmount,
  incrementAsync,
  incrementIfOdd,
} from './counterSlice';
import styles from './Counter.module.css';

const mapState = (state: RootState) => {
  return {
    count: state.counter.value
  }
}

const mapDispatch = (dispatch: AppDispatch) => {
  return {
    decrement: bindActionCreators(decrement, dispatch),
    increment: bindActionCreators(increment, dispatch),
    incrementByAmount: bindActionCreators(incrementByAmount, dispatch),
    incrementAsync: bindActionCreators(incrementAsync, dispatch),
    incrementIfOdd: bindActionCreators(incrementIfOdd, dispatch),
  }
}

type TypeofMapState = ReturnType<typeof mapState>;
type TypeofMapDispatch = ReturnType<typeof mapDispatch>;

type Ipros = TypeofMapState & TypeofMapDispatch;

class CounterComp extends Component<Ipros> {
  state = {
    incrementAmount: '2'
  }

  setIncrementAmount = (incrementAmount: string) => {
    this.setState({ incrementAmount });
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}

const Counter = connect<TypeofMapState, TypeofMapDispatch>(mapState, mapDispatch)(CounterComp);

export {
  Counter
}
```

[image]

I do not know what is wrong, I only add connect type arguments with TypeofMapState and TypeofDispatch.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
const Counter = connect<TypeofMapState, TypeofMapDispatch, {}, RootState>(mapState, mapDispatch)(CounterComp);
```

to resolve this error